# Throw error when JSON has missing properties in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Assume the following files on Cloud Storage:

`data-with-missing-column.csv`:

```
first_column
A
B
```

`data-with-missing-column.jsonl`:

```
{"first_column":"A"}
{"first_column":"B"}
```

The following script throws the error `Invalid value: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 1, but line contains only 1 columns`, which is the behavior what I want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE test_table (
  first_column STRING,
  second_column STRING
);

LOAD DATA INTO TEMPORARY TABLE test_table (
  first_column STRING,
  second_column STRING
)
FROM FILES(
  format='CSV',
  uris = ['gs://bucket-name/data-with-missing-column.csv'],
  skip_leading_rows=1
);
```

However, the following script works without issues, which is not the behavior that I want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE test_table (
  first_column STRING,
  second_column STRING
);

LOAD DATA INTO TEMPORARY TABLE test_table (
  first_column STRING,
  second_column STRING
)
FROM FILES(
  format='CSV',
  uris = ['gs://bucket-name/data-with-missing-column.jsonl']
);
```

I would have wanted the last script to work properly only if the null columns were explicitly specified as follows:

`data-with-missing-column.jsonl`:

```
{"first_column":"A","second_column":null}
{"first_column":"B","second_column":null}
```

Is there a way to obtain this behavior? Note that defining `second_column` as non-nullable is not option for me. Besides, it works with CSV when `second_column` is nullable but not with JSON. If it's possible to load columns that are arrays of structs using a CSV (instead of JSON), that could work as well.

Comment: Hi @Utku, Have you tried uploading the files or data through the BigQuery console ? Are you facing the same issue with the console also ?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced these scenarios as per the examples you have provided and we will get an error message when we provide the **`format = CSV`** with the `jsonl` file but when you change the **`format = json`** for the `jsonl` file you will not receive any error message which is an intended behavior of the json file with the BigQuery SQL as per this [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/json-data#extract_values_as_json).

If a member with the specified name is not found in the JSON object, or if the JSON array doesn't have an element with the specified position, then these operators return SQL NULL. Also, if the schema of the table is already specified then an extra column in the data file is not allowed but a column less is allowed as it can be set to NULL.

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a light-weight data interchange format that lets you describe data structures on the fly. JSON-encoded strings are composed of a hierarchy of key-value pairs that can be as simple or as complex as needed. More importantly, the actual structure of the object is determined at run-time and does not need to be predefined.